# I can not update same document multiple times in FOR loop in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection or users and I need to update the property "cuantity" twice in a loop. For example in the update array I need to to increase it by 1 and then increase it by 2, so if the actual value is 1 the result value must be 4,but it does not happen this way. ArangoDB seams to take the last update object in the update array loop and dismiss the previous update objects in the loop.

This is my collection (for make testing simple):

```
{"_key": "1", "name":"ivan", "cuantity":1}
{"_key": "2", "name":"juan", "cuantity":1}
{"_key": "3", "name":"carl", "cuantity":1}
```

This is my query and the update array

```
let updateData = [
  { user_key: "1", cuantity: 1},
  { user_key: "1", cuantity: 2},
  { user_key: "2", cuantity: 1},
  { user_key: "2", cuantity: 3}
  ]

FOR e IN updateData
  LET doc = DOCUMENT(CONCAT("test1/",e.user_key))
  UPDATE doc WITH { cuantity: doc.cuantity + e.cuantity }
  IN test1
  LET updated = NEW
RETURN updated
```

This is the result

```
[
  {
    "_key": "1", "_id": "test1/1",
    "name": "ivan",
    "cuantity": 2
  },
  {
    "_key": "1", "_id": "test1/1",
    "name": "ivan",
    "cuantity": 3
  },
  {
    "_key": "2", "_id": "test1/2",
    "name": "sergio",
    "cuantity": 2
  },
  {
    "_key": "2", "_id": "test1/2",
    "name": "sergio",
    "cuantity": 4
  }
]
```

The result of that operation must be that user with "_key": "1" has "cuantity": 4, because in the first iteration it was increased by 1 and in the second iteration by 2. The problem seems to be that ArangoDB cant update the document based in a previous update in the same loop. ¿There is a workaroud o a configuration to achieve this?
I am using RocksDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

Arango 3.4 seems to always update the original value when doing updates in a loop. I just ran this on my machine directly in the webGUI :

```
let myData = [
{ user_key: "1", cuantity: 1},
{ user_key: "1", cuantity: 2},
{ user_key: "2", cuantity: 1},
{ user_key: "2", cuantity: 3},
{ user_key: "3", cuantity: 2}
]

For entry in myData
  LET doc = DOCUMENT(CONCAT("test4/",entry.user_key))
  UPDATE doc WITH { cuantity: doc.cuantity + entry.cuantity }
  IN test4
  LET updated = NEW
RETURN updated
```

Assuming cuantity for user_key was 1 before the update, I ended up with the incorrect value of 3 instead of 4 by the end of the update.

Having said that, I would think that you may want to aggregate your data before doing the update. For example, if the value for user_key = 1 was updated 100 times in the batch, you probably do not want to run the update 100 times as it could lead to a performance issue. If you pre-aggregate, you could just update the record once at the end. So for example you could do something similar to the following :

```
let myData = [
{ user_key: "1", cuantity: 1},
{ user_key: "1", cuantity: 2},
{ user_key: "2", cuantity: 1},
{ user_key: "2", cuantity: 3},
{ user_key: "3", cuantity: 2}
]


 LET aggData = ( FOR entry IN myData
  COLLECT theKey = entry.user_key 
  AGGREGATE addedCuantity = sum(entry.cuantity)
  RETURN {theKey, addedCuantity}
  )

  FOR aggEntry IN aggData
  LET doc = DOCUMENT(CONCAT("test4/",aggEntry.theKey))
  UPDATE doc WITH { cuantity: doc.cuantity + aggEntry.addedCuantity }
  IN test4
  LET updated = NEW
  RETURN updated
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have reproduced it on my machine, also on the webGIU and the result has been different. And yes, my question is about whether you can update the same document twice in a loop. Are you using RocksDB engine? I will update my question with the exact code I ran.

Comment: Well, I just reran the example in a newly upgraded DB to 3.4 and you are correct, the last update wins. My guess is that Document() pulls the last committed revision or  it is caching. Anyways, I do not know if the upgrade changed the behavior or I should get an F in math for not knowing how to add numbers, either way I apologize for the confusion. However, my advice about aggregating the data instead of doing multiple updates is still valid. Aggregating will solve your problem and avoid potential performance issue due to multiple updates. I am updating my post to reflect the latest findings.